# reset database Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys

I have a sql file formed by tables that hold a list (species), then a main table (animal) that references that table like:

```
DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_species`; 
CREATE  TABLE `tbl_species` (
    specie                  VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB             DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tbl_species`   VALUES ('dog');
INSERT INTO `tbl_species`   VALUES ('cat');
INSERT INTO `tbl_species`   VALUES ('bird');

DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_animal`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_animal` (
    id_animal   INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "no nombre",
    specie      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT "dog",
    FOREIGN KEY (specie)        REFERENCES `tbl_species`     (specie),
    CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_Animal` UNIQUE (`id_animal`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB                 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This works on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6597c) with no problem but when I execute the sql file on server
I get the following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Statement:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_species`
```

Could you please tell how to solve this issue, Currently I have to drop database and create it again... so the drops statements are causing problems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `Cannot delete or update` error is that the `tbl_animal` table already exists. The tables need to be dropped in the opposite order of creation:

```
DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_animal`; 
DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_species`; 

CREATE  TABLE `tbl_species` (
    specie                  VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB             DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tbl_species`   VALUES ('dog');
INSERT INTO `tbl_species`   VALUES ('cat');
INSERT INTO `tbl_species`   VALUES ('bird');

CREATE TABLE `tbl_animal` (
    id_animal   INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "no nombre",
    specie      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT "dog",
    FOREIGN KEY (specie)        REFERENCES `tbl_species`     (specie),
    CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_Animal` UNIQUE (`id_animal`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB                 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Alternatively, you could preface the commands with:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Which will disable foreign key checks for the current session.

To reenable foreign key checks, add the following command afterwards:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

See a working example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6727

Answer (score 1):

You either have to delete the foreign key table before dropping the dependant table, or drop and re-create the foreign key every time you drop the table.

Try this, it will drop and re-create the tables every time: (My version of SQL server is 2012)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_animal', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.tbl_animal
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_species', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.tbl_species

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_species](
    [specie] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_species] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [specie] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO tbl_species   VALUES ('dog');
INSERT INTO tbl_species   VALUES ('cat');
INSERT INTO tbl_species   VALUES ('bird');

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal](
    [id_animal] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [specie] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_animal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_animal] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_animal_name]  DEFAULT ('no nombre') FOR [name]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_animal_specie]  DEFAULT ('dog') FOR [specie]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_animal_tbl_species] FOREIGN KEY([specie])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_species] ([specie])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_animal_tbl_species]
GO
```

If you wanted to give it a go, here are scripts you can use (when the tables already exist):
Drop constraint, then table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal]  drop CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_animal_tbl_species] 
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_species', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.tbl_species
go
```

Drop constraint, then recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal]  drop CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_animal_tbl_species] 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_animal]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_animal_tbl_species] FOREIGN KEY([specie])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_species] ([specie])
GO
```

With these you could modify the script so you don't have to drop the animal table every time.